# Working with team in Git

Tags: git, github

I am working in a team on a git project and I really don't understand the process we should be following.

1. I clone the project I am working on from Github
2. I then checkout the develop branch to do my work
3. I do a `git add .; git commit -a` to add my new files

But as I was working some of the other team players added new files so now Git gives me a error on `git push`.

What command should I run right before my push to see if anyone changed anything?

Comment: Can you show what error message Git gives you when you try to push?

Comment: also if you do git add . you don't need to use commit -a  you can just use commit.   But you need to discuss with your team what your process is. we do all of our work in feature branches,  push the feature branch up to GH, then use GH to issue a pull request to merge it to master .

Comment: The `git pull origin <branch>'` command is what you're looking for (but checking on your host (Github for example) isn't too bad either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `git pull`.

This command will perform a `git fetch` to get the changes made by your colleagues. Then it would try to perform `git merge` which will merge their changes onto your local working tree.

If the merge is not successful you will need to resolve the conflicts.

Then you will be able to perform `git push` and your colleagues will need to pull your changes  before they push.

P.S. If you have trouble using this process you could use a visual git client like GitHub, Tower, SmartGit or others.

Comment: Visual Git clients can be nice (I use TortoiseGit for viewing log history), but I wouldn't depend on them, because they don't really help you understand how to use Git well.  If you want to become good at using Git, you **have to** use it from the command line.

Comment: Of course! I've been using git from the command line longer than I was using it with a visual client. Unfortunately if you haven't made the effort to learn the basics like the `pull` command I think you'll just leave Git altogether if you don't use the convenience of an external client.

Answer (score 3):

Using `git fetch <remote repo alias>` will allow you to preview upstream changes in your develop branch.

You would then want to either merge those changes into your local work, or rebase your local changes on top of the remote work, then try push to the remote repo again.

Here's how you would merge the remote changes:

```
git merge <remote>/develop
```

And this is the command you would use to rebase instead:

```
git rebase <remote>/develop
```

Both would get you the same end-state for your develop branch.

Comment: The terms "upstream", "merge" and "rebase" might need some further explaination for a git beginner.

Comment: Those commands would not achieve the same state for the branch, only the same state for the tree. The merge option would preserve all of the original commits and add a new merge commit, the rebase option would create new versions of the old local commits and discard the originals.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that the end-state of the code, in the final commit, would be the same in either situation.  But as you point out, the history for the branch wouldn't be the same if you did `merge` vs `rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do git `git fetch` will retrieve the updated. After that you can check how the repository is doing `git status` that will show you the status of your clone compared with the one you cloned from.